# Is there any way to simulate django collectstatic command during development?

Tags: python, django

I'm working on React App and after that I want to make a bundle.js file and place it in **assets/bundles/** folder.

I'm using [django-webpack-loader](https://github.com/ezhome/django-webpack-loader)

Here's my **settings.py** file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
 ...
 'webpack_loader',
)

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets'),
)

STATIC_URL = '/media/static/'

WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    'DEFAULT': {
        'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': 'bundles/',
        'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'webpack-stats.json'),
    }
}
```

Here's my **template.html**:

```
<div id="container"></div>

{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}
{% render_bundle 'main' %}
```

The error I get is:

> GET *example.com/media/static/bundles/bundle.js* 404 (Not Found)

If I run

> python manage.py collectstatic

It will move **bundle.js** from **assets/bundles/** to **media/static/bundles**. But I don't want to run it every time I'm changing my bundle.

In the [django-webpack-loader](https://github.com/ezhome/django-webpack-loader) documentation collectstatic command is not run but the bundle.js still can be accessed as though it's in static folder. But actually it's located in assets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
./manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

If you have a lot of duplicates you can use `--clear` method

```
./manage.py collectstatic --clear
```

If you struggle adding the package you can search for the Path to the JS like:

```
./manage.py findstatic js/bundle.js
```

read more about the command [here](http://django-staticfiles.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/commands.html#findstatic)